# Can we not do away with the 'systems' of citation?

Tags: journals

There's a big melodrama happening around the issue of citation in articles. Some journal accepts one citation system whereas the other journal insists on some other system. The authors, unfortunately, have had to concentrate more upon how to cite rather than how to make their valid points in representing their research.

Comment: This is fixed by software - citation managers can easily generate citations in whatever format is desired, so the author doesn't have to think about it at all, except in obscure corner cases.

Comment: That's why there are type-setters. I moonlighted as one, and one of the biggest hassles was fixing the citations to match the format of the journal. (You wouldn't believe how many people prepare bad .bib files, even in this day and age of MathSciNet. I don't even want to know how bad it is for other fields.)

Comment: I am voting to close this "question", as there is no real question here but rather a rant over different citation systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are too worried about the formatting troubles of your work, it would be a better time to switch to **LaTeX**. The initial investment to learn the basics should save you a whole lot of time in future.

**BibTeX** is a feature that works with LaTeX to manage citations. You can get BibTeX entries from most popular online journal repositories (as bib files). I prefer Google Scholar Button to ease out citation collection.

Collecting them would be one thing but storing and managing them across papers would be another. To relieve from these troubles, **reference managers** were invented. There are many available, (EndNote, Mendeley, BibDesk, etc.) and you just have to choose which one works for you.

Comment: JabRef is a reference manager for LaTeX/BibTeX.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog I prefer that for cross platform purposes too :-) I guess that should be covered in the 'etc.' part.